# Laravel & JQuery : Get the correct positions of draggables in a droppable image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, canvas

Hello I'm implementing a basic esignature for our client using documents from their users, and i'm trying to use jquery UI draggable over an image. Here are my sample code

```
<style>
        h5 {
            border: 2px solid gray;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        img {
            width: 100%;
            position:absolute;
            left:0px;
            top:0px;
            z-index:-1;
        }
        
    </style>


<body>
<div>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="position: absolute;bottom: 0px;left: 0px;right: 0px;top: 0px;">
        <h1>ProClient ESignature</h1>
        <div class="row" style="height: 100%;margin-left: -15px;margin-right: -15px;position: relative;">
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="position:absolute; height: 100%; width: 25%; position: absolute; top:0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;">
                <h5 class="draggable">Signature</h5>
                <h5 class="draggable">Date</h5>
                <h5 class="draggable">Name</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-11 droppable" style="height: 100%; width: 75%; position: absolute; top:0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px">
                <img id="imagesrc" src="{{ url($files[0]) }}" width="100%" style="padding:0px; margin:0px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        stack: ".draggable"
    }).resizable();
    $('.droppable').droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
    });
</script>
```

Yes I'm able to drag and simulate a signature box, and I know that droppable has an api DROP function that has event and ui parameters where I can get the position object with X and Y coordinates. However it seems that these coordinates as specifically for the image container that contains the image not relative to the image itself. Is there a way to get it correctly or I need to compute for it given the values that I have ? also if I scaled the image to a lower version then will the coordinates need to be multiplied by the scale value/percentage ?

Comment: you can make a parent and  `containment: ".cp-view",`  then from parent x y will be absolute

Comment: @KamleshPaul what do you mean? sorry front-end not really my strong skill